The bias variance tradeoff and linear regression
Here is what is what is written about the bias-variance tradeoff in "Introduction to Statistical Learning":

I am wondering, how to relate this to the linear regression model? Do we have in the bias-variance tradeoff that the $X$ vector used to construct $\hat{f}$ is itself random? So we need the distribution of $X$ as well? The reason this confuses be is that from what I recall in linear regression we only assume that $Y$ is random, but that the points $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are fixed, and all the tests we make are under this assumption that $X$ is not random?

You're right that in the basic linear regression model we assume that $X$ is not random. However, we do estimate $\beta$ and thus you can see that the fitted values (which are basically given by $\hat{f}$) are indeed random
$$\hat{y} = \hat{f}(X) = X \hat{\beta}$$.
See also here for an application to the linear regression model.

Thank you, yes I agree with what you are saying. But is it so that for the linear regression model we have that $Var(\hat{f}(x_0))$ and $[Bias(\hat{f}(x_0))]^2$ are calculated under the assumption that the when we have the training data $(x_1,y_1), \ldots (x_n,y_n)$ the points $x_k$ are fixed and the only randomness is in $y$? But in genereal the bias-variance tradeoff formula can also handle that the points $x_k$ in the training data are random?, which means that the randmness of $\hat{f}$ comes from randomness in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$?

So the randomness is coming from $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ as you've rightly point out. Are you referring to model selection? You can also have randomness in $\hat{f}$ by just specifying a 'wrong' model. Nevertheless, as far as I understand it, the $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ itself are fixed and deterministic.
